# Links inside Carousel

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Can we use links inside Carousel. I want to show the list of items to the user. Each item will contain the title, image and description. Now when user will tap on any item image, it should trigger an user query like the item title and when user clicks on the link inside description, it should be redirected to web.

In other words I want to use both Carousel and Browsing Carousel feature with each list item.

Is there anything like it ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documents you cannot use links in a carousel. If you want to use links, the documents recommend to use a browsing carousel instead.

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#carousel

Sadly tapping a browsing carousel only opens links. So theres not one element which allows you to both. What you could try is using a carousel and add linkOut suggestion chips to allow users to use the carousel for user input and the chips for browser navigation.

Comment: Using LinkOutSuggestion will not be a feasible solution when there are more than 3 or 4 carousels.

Comment: Then I think it might be challenging to do it in a single response, I don't know any other responses that allow you to open links and also continue the conversation by touch. What you could try is using a carousel and in the next response send a basic card with the description and link, if that works for your current solution.